# Ho can i get deep nested angular ui route views?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Somehow i think i am misunderstanding how uirouter works. I cannot figure out why the following code does not work as expected. until "modal_view" everything works a sexpected, but "modal_view.child" is not showing where i expect it to be? What am i doing wrong?

My route structure is like this:

```
    $stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                url: '',
                template: '<div><h1>This is my main State Template</h1><div ui-view="benefy_modal"></div><p>Some other content related to main view...</p></div>',
                controller: 'MainController',
                abstract: true,
            })
            .state('app.modal_view', {
                url: '/modal_view',
                views: {
                    'modal_view': {
                        template: '',
                        controller: ['$mdDialog', function ($mdDialog) {
                            $mdDialog.show({
                                scope: $scope.$new(),
                                template: '<md-dialog aria-label="modal"><md-dialog-content><ui-view>********expect "view1" to go here!*********</ui-view></md-dialog-content></md-dialog>'
                            });
                        }]
                    }
                },
                abstract: true
            })
            .state('app.modal_view.child', {
                url: '/child',
                views: {
                    'view1': {
                        templateUrl: '<p>view1</p>'
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: I will suggest you to go to this site and you will get whatever you need                                                            https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router

Comment: Sorry cant figure it out.

Comment: @AdeshKumar your link does not address the user's direct problem of correctly displaying deeply nested views (more than one level down)